# Can someone please help me in setting up OAuth server and client implementation in PHP?

Tags: php, oauth

Even after lots of googling I could only find very basic and raw examples which are very difficult to understand. Can someone please help me in setting up OAuth server and client implementation in PHP? 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a simple class in PHP for Google oAuth available [here](http://www.silviosilva.com/article-images/oauth2/OAuthGoogle.zip)

I've also implemented other Facebook and Microsoft oAuth on other projects and they are similar but don't work exactly the same way. The differences I remember are:

- Some require requests to be send by POST others by GET
- Facebook doesn't send all replies in JSON format

You can read my small tutorial [here](http://www.silviosilva.com/article/oauth2), the site itself uses that class and oAuth login :)